# Errors while porting cocos2d-x project to android

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have successfully run the "Step by Step Coos2dxSimpleGame Series" (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Tutorials) in windows using visual c++. Now I want to port this project to an android device, Hence I copied the classes namely HelloWorld,AppDelegate and GameOverScene and their header files to Classes folder and the resources to /Resources folder. Then I have modified the android.mk file to include a new class called GameOverScene.cpp which is not present before .

Then I run ./build_native.sh . The error message is here (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/1152/native_error.PNG) .
Is the process I am following correct?

Comment: Can you post your HelloWorld class ? You are probably using a namespace and using it again as a prefix in your class

Comment: I actually didn't change anything much which have been generated by a hello world app. I have changed just the font  to Arial and text size to 20 .`CCLabelTTF* pLabel = CCLabelTTF::labelWithString("Hello World", "Arial", 20);`  Just to make sure that any changes are getting validated. But errors have proned.

Comment: What's in your HelloWorldScene.h at lines 40 and 41 ?

Comment: Here, I have uploaded the entire project to this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/1e6acp9583ytprm/ninja_attack.zip

Answer (score 0):

In HelloWorldScene.h, change:

```
HelloWorld::~HelloWorld();
HelloWorld::HelloWorld();
```

to:

```
~HelloWorld();
HelloWorld();`
```

You must not add the class name in your declarations in header files (but you have to do it in your cpp file).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can suggest You is to follow step by step this tutorial

http://magicscrollsofcode.blogspot.com/2011/09/quick-and-dirty-guide-to-getting.html

and also don't forget about this:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/8572?r=8577#message-8577 afterwards

these two things helped me a lot one time :)